# How to Change the Design of Datagridview in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to change the color of my DataGridView headers. I tried to use properties but it's not working. Also, how to remove the first blank column if it is possible?

[image: DataGridView headers]

What I tried:

```
DataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.fromArgb(44,62,80)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you seem to want to change the color of the ColumnHeaders, not the RowHeaders. Either way, in order to change the style of the DataGridView headers, you need to disable the [`EnableHeadersVisualStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.enableheadersvisualstyles) property:

```
DataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(44, 62, 80)
DataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(44, 62, 80)
```

Note that disabling the `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` property would make the headers look different though because it loses the visual styles of the current Windows theme:

[image: EnableHeadersVisualStyles]

> ...and remove the first blank column if it is possible.

That *first blank column* is called the RowHeaders. You can hide/show it by setting the value of `RowHeadersVisible` and you can also change its width by changing the `RowHeadersWidth` property:

```
DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False
'DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 20
```

Or, you can do the same in design time by setting these values in the Properties Window.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.